# AngularJs UI-Router FutureStates not working with urlRouterProvider.otherwise

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm working on a AngularJS project which uses dynamic states based on the future state mechanism of UI-Router-Extras (http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/future]). The future state mechanism works fine except the following:

If I use `urlRouterProvider.otherwise()` in the application config block the future state routing doesn't work anymore.

```
app.config(['$futureStateProvider', '$controllerProvider', '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($futureStateProvider, $controllerProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $urlRouterProvider.when("", "/start");
  $urlRouterProvider.when("/", "/start");
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/error"); /* !!! --> no route to future state possible anymore */

  $stateProvider
  .state('start', {
     url: "/start",
     templateUrl: "start.html",
     controller: 'DemoMainCtrl'
   })
   .state('error', {
      url: "/error",
      templateUrl: "error.html"
   })
   ... some more states ...    

  /* here comes the code for the futute state setup as in the example: 
  http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/example/future/index.html#/
  whioch works fine as long as I'm not using $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/error")*/
```

Any hints how to apply `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/error");` the correct way or how to use any other automatic error routing mechanism (i.e. automatic route to an error view in case a state or URL is not available)?

Comment: Yeah, .otherwise doesn't work currently.  https://github.com/christopherthielen/ui-router-extras/issues/39

Comment: Oh, can you suggest any other simple workaround for that scenario?

Comment: 0.0.11 is going to add .otherwise support.  It should be released soon.  You can build ui-router-extras from `master` if you need it today.

Comment: Thanks, this are good news!

Answer (score 1):

Circling back around, .otherwise() now works in 0.0.11+

https://github.com/christopherthielen/ui-router-extras/issues/39